# ABCD is a square, M, N, E are the midpoint of AD, DC, DN respectively, J is the intersection point of BE and AN.

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a square, M, N, E are the midpoint of AD, DC, DN respectively, J is the intersection point of BE and AN.
Prove:

a) BM perpendicular AN

b) MJ perpendicular BE

---

a) is an easy one, I solved it already.

b) I can finish it if AB = BJ is proved.

Or ∆DJN is a right angle

Or DJ parallel BM

Or by calling F is midpoint of BC and $J\in DF$

But I can't prove any of them

Please help me one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let the side length of the square be $4x$, you can see $EC=3x$ and therefore $BE=5x$. However since ${BJ\over JE}={AB\over EN}={4\over 1}$, we now $BJ=4x=AB$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $DM^2=DE\cdot DC$. So $DA$ is tangent to $(CEM)$. But we can also see that $DA$ is tangent to $(BMC)$. So we get that $C$, $M$ lie on the circle with diameter $\overline{BE}$.

So the reflection of $E$ over $BM$ lies on $AB$. Since $AJ\perp BM$, it follows that the reflection of $J$ over $BM$ is $A$. Hence $\angle MJB=\angle BAM=90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Amazing answer!